# How to clone a DOM element/template using angular and preserve its binding?

Tags: angular, clone, directive, sticky

I am trying to create a sticky directive that makes the element on which it is present sticky while scrolling (like a sticky header). The way I intend to do this is by first cloning the DOM element/template the directive is present on and as you scroll up the clone sticks to the top using `position: fixed, top: 0, width: blapx`. The reason for using the clone is to ensure the viewport height doesn't change and there isn't a jump in the layout. Since the clone uses the `position: fixed` it needs to be an exact replica of the original element/DOM and preserve all of it's binding.

I have tried creating a directive called `sticky` that you could place on the element that you want to make sticky as you scroll. 
My initial idea was using `this.viewRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef` inside the directive. But the directive only gets access to `ViewContainerRef` and `ElementRef` and NOT `TemplateRef` since it isn't a structural directive. 
I do not intend to use `structural directive` since we could only have one stuctural directive per element and this could be restrictive. 
For eg, I intend to use this sticky directive on the table header which is constructed using `cdk-table` and the header row uses `<tr *cdkHeaderRowDef></tr>` so I can't really use a structural directive here.
Also, the `cdk-table` doesn't allow inserting any other tags/components except for `table tags`.

Also, I can't use the `resolveFactory(component)` inside the directive since the directive could be present on a simple DOM element such as as a `div`. For eg.,
`<div class="header" sticky> contents here.. </div>`

Also, I wouldn't like to use `position: sticky` as it doesn't have full cross-browser support.

Due to these restrictions I would like to make use of an attribute directive to meet all the requirements.

Example usage of my directive. Note, it could also be present on 2 or more elements in the view. In this case the second one sticks below the first one and so on.. This is just additional info and not really relates to the original problem.

```
<div class="header" sticky>
 Title of the page
 <button class="btn btn-default"> Save</button>
</div>
```

```
<tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="selectedColumnIds" sticky>
</tr>
```

```
<summary-element sticky>...some content</summar-element>
```

In the above sample I would like to clone the elements using the `sticky` directive present on each of them and also make sure 
 - directive clones them when they are rendered in the view
 - the clone changes when the actual element changes.

`Angular: 7.0.2`

Comment: it seems like all you need is to inject ElementRef and clone it using [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) DOM API

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard the `clone` DOM api doesn't do a recursive cloning (only clones upto 1 level). Also cloning and injecting the `cloned element` doesn't trigger angular bindings. For eg, any directives present on the original element would they work on the cloned node? Thanks

Comment: yeah, that's correct. then a structural directive is the only option I guess

Comment: hmm.. I see.. this is tricky. `Angular 1` provided the `$compile` option and you could just grab the `outerHTML` and `$compile` it and done. Do you see any other approach for achieving the `sticky` approach? thanks for the response @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard

Comment: yeah, you can similar approach in Angular, [check this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99)

Comment: Thanks for the article @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard. But there are a few shortcomings u mention in that approach of the compiled element not picking up `ngOnChanges` and we also make use of `AOT` compilation in our project. I am just wondering why such a simple thing is being made so complicated? I feel like there is no way to achieve this at this point.

Comment: yeah, I agree, the process is overly complicated now, but these dynamic things should be a lot easier with Ivy

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard